# Unknown bytes while reading an image from ImageIO after sending it with ImageIO

Tags: java, image, sockets, javax.imageio

While transfering images over the network using sockets, I had a -for me- strange issue:
When I wrote images to the `OutputStream` of one socket with `ImageIO.write()` and read the same images from the `InputStream` of the other socket with `ImageIO.read()` I noticed, that 16 bytes per image were sent more than read.
To be able to send multiple images in a row I had to read these bytes after every call of `ImageIO.read()` to not receive `null` because the input could not be parsed.

Does anybody know, why this is so and what these bytes are?

In this piece of code I have extracted the issue:

```
public class Test implements Runnable
{
    public static final int COUNT = 5;

    public void run()
    {
        try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3040))
        {
            Socket client = server.accept();
            for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
            {
                final BufferedImage image = readImage(client.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(image);
            }
        } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage readImage(InputStream stream) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(stream);

        dontKnowWhy(stream);

        return image;
    }

    private void dontKnowWhy(InputStream stream) throws IOException
    {
        stream.read(new byte[16]);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new Thread(new Test()).start();

        try(Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 3040))
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
            {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); //
                int[] vals = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];                     //
                Arrays.fill(vals, new Random().nextInt());                                      // Create random image
                image.setRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), vals, 0, 1);            //

                ImageIO.write(image, "png", server.getOutputStream());  //send image to server

                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();             //
                while(time + 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis());    //wait a second
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I am glad about any answers, already thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "extra" bytes you see, is not read, simply because they are not needed to correctly decode the image (they are, however, most likely needed to form a fully compliant file in the chosen file format, so they are not just random "garbage" bytes).

For any given `ImageIO` plugin, the number of bytes left in the stream after a read may be `0`, `16`or any other number. It might depend on the format, the writer that wrote it, the reader, the number of images in the input, the metadata in the file, etc. In other words, relying on this behavior would be an error.

The easies way to fix this, is to prepend *each image* with a byte count, containing the length of the output image. This typically means you need to buffer the response on the client, to either a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (in-memory) or a `FileOutputStream` (disk).

The client then needs to read the byte count for the image, and make sure you skip any remaining bytes after the read. This can be accomplished by wrapping the input (see `FilterInputStream`) and keep track of the byte count internally.

(You can also read all the bytes up front, and wrapping them in a `ByteArrayInputStream`, before passing the data to `ImageIO.read()`, which is simpler but does more in-memory buffering).

After this, the client is ready do start over, by reading a new byte count, and a new image.

Another approach if you'd like less buffering on the server, could be to implement something like [HTTP chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), where you have multiple smaller blocks (chunks) sent to the client for each image, each prepended with its own byte count. You would need to handle the last chunk of each image especially, or insert special delimiter chunks to mark end of stream or start of a new stream.

Code below implements the buffering approach on the server, while using direct reading on the client.

Server:

```
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (...) {
    buffer.reset();
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", buffer);

    stream.writeInt(buffer.size());
    buffer.writeTo(stream); // Send image to server
}
```

Client:

```
DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

for (...) {
    int size = stream.readInt();

    try (InputStream imageData = new SubStream(stream, size)) {
        return ImageIO.read(imageData);
    }
    // Note: imageData implicitly closed using try-with-resources
}
```

...

```
// Util class
private static final class SubStream extends FilterInputStream {
    private final long length;
    private long pos;

    public SubStream(final InputStream stream, final long length) {
        super(stream);

        this.length = length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean markSupported() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return (int) Math.min(super.available(), length - pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (pos++ >= length) {
            return -1;
        }

        return super.read();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (pos >= length) {
            return -1;
        }

        int count = super.read(b, off, (int) Math.min(len, length - pos));

        if (count < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        pos += count;

        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        if (pos >= length) {
            return -1;
        }

        long skipped = super.skip(Math.min(n, length - pos));

        if (skipped < 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        pos += skipped;

        return skipped;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Don't close wrapped stream, just consume any bytes left
        while (pos < length) {
            skip(length - pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and how can I know exacly how many bytes are remaining? When I send another image right after the first, there is no difference between the "extra bytes" and the bytes of the next image. Trying to read the second after every extra byte to see if it now starts would be very inefficient

Comment: You count how many bytes the `ImageReader` did consume. This can be accomplished either by wrapping the input (`FilterInputStream`) and keep track of the byte count. Another approach is reading all the bytes up front, and wrapping in a `ByteArrayInputStream`. The whole point of the byte count is to know exactly how many bytes to read, there's no need to guess or try.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand it yet. Lets say I am on a client which receives exactly 1 000 000 bytes and I know that there are 3 images to read. How can I know where the second and the third begins? There must be anything in the image format, which the images are send in, that tells me: Image read finished

Comment: I think with your solution I had to buffer the image on the server and the client. Then I could send the total number of bytes, which one image has before the actual image. On the client side I could read all bytes into a buffer with the size of the bytes of this image and let the `ImageIO.read()` read from there. But this means a lot more lag than just letting `ImageIO` handling all the buffer things, am I right? Is it possible without this?

Comment: With 3 images, you will have three byte counts, each telling the length of the next image stream (I edited the answer to make this clearer). Some image formats contain stream size, most don't. If you'd like less buffering on the server, you could implement something like HTTP chunked transfer encoding. And finally yes, it's possible to not buffer on the client, as I wrote in my answer, you just wrap the input stream, and then count bytes until you have read up to the byte count (or if read is done and you haven't, you just skip the remaining bytes).

Comment: ok, it is clearer now. I`d have never thought that something like this would be necessary to transfer images! But thanks a lot for your answers, it has really helped understanding this!

Comment: Good stuff! Actually, the problem isn't strictly related to images, it's about reliably transferring dynamically generated data (with unknown length). :-)